# ng-class in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.5

I am developing a test application in angular 2 and I'm stuck with a problem of adding classes based on list from model.

In Angular 1 one could do:

```
// model
$scope.myClasses = ['class1', 'class2', ...];

// view
... ng-class="myClasses" ...
```

In Angular 2, all I have been able to do so far is:

```
// view
... [class.class1]="true" [class.class2]="true" ...
```

Which is obviously not very dynamic and I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.

However, I have also tried:

```
// model
class ... {
    private myClasses: any;
    constructor() {
        this.myClasses = ['class1', 'class2', ...];
    }

// view
... [class]="myClasses" ...
```

but this doesn't work, I have tried `myClasses` as a string name of a single class, array of strings, object with a classname key and true as a value, an array of objects of this kind, but sadly, nothing of listed will work this way.

Comment: You can try adding them via the component's class by injecting in `elementRef:ElementRef` and referencing the class list directly. Or possibly in the view w/ your last attempt.... `this.classes = {'class1':true, 'class2':true}` and in your view `[class]="classes"`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You must specify [`CSSClass`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.22/modules/angular2/src/directives/class.js#L12) in [`directives`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.22/modules/angular2/src/core/annotations_impl/view.js#L72) property of [`@View`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.22/modules/angular2/src/core/annotations_impl/view.js#L35) decorator. Check out this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0M6BDChlt9F1PQQZBIZS?p=preview).

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
})
@View({
    template: '<div [class]="classMap">Class Map</div>',
    directives: [CSSClass]
})
class App {
    constructor() {
        this.classMap = { 'class1': true, 'class2': false };

        setInterval(() => {
            this.classMap.class2 = !this.classMap.class2;
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

**UPD**

`CSSClass` [was renamed](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/3498) to [`NgClass`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.40/modules/angular2/src/core/directives/ng_class.ts#L35) in alpha-35. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mo68CtFnrYmZ7h33SIdj?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
})
@View({
  directives: [NgClass],
  template: `
    <div [ng-class]="classMap">Class Map</div>
  `,
})
class App { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: CSSClass directive has been renamed to NgClass.

Comment: `ng-class` was changed to `ngClass`. I guess `NgClass` doesn't need to be aded to providers as well, but not sure.

Comment: beta.3 now uses `[class]` in the template, and no need to specify the directive.  (I'm sure that's not the first version to have the change, just the latest one I've used this in.)

Comment: @EricMartinez Thanks for reminding! Right now I have no time for this. I'll update the answer a little bit later.

Answer (score 39):

According to the [NgClass API docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html), Angular 2 will accept a string, an Array, or an Object/map as the expression to NgClass. Or, of course, you could specify a function that returns one of those.

```
import {Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <div ngClass="gray-border purple">string of classes</div>
      <div [ngClass]="'gray-border purple'">string of classes</div>
      <div [ngClass]="['gray-border', 'green']">array of classes</div>
      <div [ngClass]="{'gray-border': true, 'blue': true}">object/map of classes</div>
      <button [ngClass]="{active: isActive}" (click)="isActive = !isActive">Click me</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .gray-border {  border: 1px solid gray; }
    .blue   { color: blue; }
    .green  { color: green; }
    .purple { color: purple; }
    .active { background-color: #f55; }
  `]
})
export class App {
  title = "Angular 2 - NgClass";
  isActive = false;
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G8FHkGisnGFp8U0m6W7F?p=preview)</kbd>

If you are passing a literal string, note the two alternative syntaxes:

```
<div ngClass="gray-border purple">string of classes</div>
<div [ngClass]="'gray-border purple'">string of classes</div>
```

I believe the first is just syntactic sugar for the second.

And to quote the docs:

> While the NgClass directive can interpret expressions evaluating to
>   string, Array or Object, the Object-based version is the most often
>   used and has an advantage of keeping all the CSS class names in a
>   template.

Answer (score 22):

**One more method** [ Using Ternary Operator and Interpolation]

(Altough `Mark Rajcok` stated all possible `ngClass` methods, but you can couple it with `ternary operator` and you get `else` condtions)

---

### Template

```
<div class="hard-coded-class {{classCondition ? 'c1 c2': 'c3 c4'}}">
    Conditional classes using <b>Ternary Operator</b>
</div>
```

*or use `ternary operator` with `ngClass`, [**see how**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091329/5612697)*

### TS

```
export class App {
  this.classCondition = false;
}
```

### Result

```
<div class="hard-coded-class c3 c4">
      Conditional classes using <b>Ternary Operator</b>
</div>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: long time was looking/hoping for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Using typescript and Angular 2 beta, ngClass doesn't seem to work. From following the API preview -
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html

```
template: '<div [ngClass]="classMap">Class Map</div>'
```

The example from Google provides two versions of code (which I assume is Alpha and updated to Beta). The new syntax in the website example doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

```
@View({
    template: `
        <div class="container questions">
            <div class="row formSection">
                 <h2>
                     <div [ngClass]="completed">completed</div>
                </h2>
                <questionSection></questionSection>
            </div>
        </div>
        `,
        directives: [NgClass, QuestionSection],
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since the question was asked, the spec changed at least twice from what I've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar, I had a list of menu items and wanted to specify a fontawesome class for each item. This is how I made it work. In my typescript component I had this:

```
    export class AppCmp {
       menuItems = [
         {
           text: 'Editor',
           icon: 'fa fa-pencil'
         },
         {
           text: 'Account',
           icon: 'fa fa-user'
         },
         {
           text: 'Catalog',
           icon: 'fa fa-list'
         }
      ]
    }
```

Then in my html:

```
  <div *ngFor="#item of menuItems; #index = index">
        <i [attr.class]="item.icon"></i>
        <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
  </div>
```

Here is the plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/PIDRZsc7ZhISNgZzOWuY?p=preview
Hope that helps