# How to get a value from a component and use it in ngClass in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this component here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'component-a',
    templateUrl: '../html/componenta.html'
})
export class ComponetA {
 color_class:string = "red_bg";
}
```

My css for .red_bg is:

```
.red_bg{background-color:red}
```

Now, in my componenta.html, when I attach the class to a button using ngClass, it works perfect, here is the snippet `<button [ngClass]="{'red_bg': 1===1}">Click</button>`
My question is how do I use ngClass and get the value of the class name from the component? Here is what I tried but didn't work: `<button [ngClass]="{color_class: 1===1}">Click</button>`
I also tried interpolating this way `<button [ngClass]="{'{{color_class}}': 1===1}">Click</button>` but still didn't work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic classname inside ngClass in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in below way:

**HTML**

```
<div [ngClass]="getCSSClass('someExpression')">
</div>
```

**TS**

```
getCSSClass(flag:string) {
  let cssClass;

  if(flag == 'one') {  
     cssClass = {
       'one': true
     }  
  } else {  
     cssClass = {
       'two': true 
     }  
  }
  return cssClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that these works:

```
<button [ngClass]="color_class">Click</button>
```

or

```
<button [className]="color_class">Click</button>
```

or

```
<button [class]="color_class">Click</button>
```