# Dynamic CSS Classes in Angular2+

Tags: angular

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let record of lift" class="list-lifts" [class.showLifts]="isBtnActive">
```

Component:

```
isBtnActive: boolean = false;

toggleClass() {
    this.isBtnActive = !this.isBtnActive;
  }
```

CSS:

```
.list-lifts {

  &:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: -11px !important;
    display: none;
  }
}

.showLifts {
  display: block !important;
}

// I need something like this to be built in the view:
.ValueshowLifts {}
```

The `toggleClass()` function toggles the CSS class `.showLifts` on the click of a button.  This works great.

The issue is, I need the class `.showLifts` to have a dynamic name and I'm not sure what the syntax is to produce it.  For logical reasons, here's an example:

```
[class.{{ record.name }}showLifts]="isBtnActive"
```

But of course this isn't valid syntax.

Comment: `[ngClass]="{[record.name]: true}"`

Comment: Hint from user663031 is reasonable, but won't compile at '['. The expression has to be moved to a function, then it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have mentioned you can use `[ngClass]`. An answer was posted here:

[Dynamic classname inside ngClass in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2)

But I wanted to mention that if you're using **CSS** to only hide or show elements, then instead you can use `*ngIf` or `[hidden]`, depending if you want the element in the DOM or not.

Answer (score 7):

You can leverage ngClass directive here

```
[ngClass]="showLiftsClass"
```

Inside your code you can dynamically add css classes to it as follows,

```
showLiftsClass = {
      'record1showLifts' : true,
      'record2showLifts' : false,
      'record3showLifts' : false,
      'record4showLifts' : false
      ...
}
```

You can have single or multiple classes as a *true*. Value *true* will add the class to the DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="form-group label-floating" 
    [ngClass]="{'is-empty': true, 'second-class' : true}"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let record of lift; ; let i=index" class="list-lifts" 
[ngClass]="{'showLifts': isBtnActive}">
```

> Or you can Use: *ngIf

```
*ngIf="expression" (e.g. *ngIf="i!=0" or *ngIf="i==0")
```

Comment: The class toggling works, but I'm still stuck at square one with the issue.  I need the class .showLifts to have an appended string such as {{ record.name }}.

Comment: like this? <span [ngClass]="{'showLifts': isBtnActive}">{{record.name}}</span>

Comment: or you can not want toggling for string then, <span [ngClass]="{'showLifts': true}">{{record.name}}</span> or  <span [ngClass]="{'showLifts': false}">{{record.name}}</span>

Comment: That won't work, let me try to explain it better:

These divs are being built dynamically using *ngFor, and they are split into 4 categories.  I'm hiding everything except the first-child of each category using display:none.  onClick, a CSS class with display: block gets added to show the children.

I need the CSS class to be dynamic because without it, every category becomes visible by clicking any button.

Comment: you can use index of record, i have updated anwer. by perticular index you can hide or show element. like [ngClass]="{'list-lifts': i==0}"