# How to make fallback values in a NgStyle object

Tags: javascript, css, angular

In the html I can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to write:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
```

Where objExp returns

```
    return {
        "background": "red"
    };
```

This works, and turns the background of the element to red.

There are times when I want a fallback values. For example, if I was dealing with gradients I would need `-webkit-linear-gradient`, `-o-linear-gradient` then `linear-gradient`.
I can't add multiple values with the same key to a javascript object.

I guessed at

```
return { "background": ["red", "blue"] }
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried `{ "background: "red, blue" }`

I don't want to use the `<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>` because that loads complexity repetitively into my html. I can't use `[style]="expresionThatGivesAString"` because it breaks in Safari.

"red" and "blue" are set at runtime, which is why I'm binding them straight to the element. So putting them in classes isn't an option.

**How do I set multiple background values using ngStyle?**

Comment: Can't you use `NgClass` to do that ?

Comment: @trichetriche Maybe, I can't see how.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2

Comment: ? Red and blue aren't classnames here, I mean #ff0000 and #0000ff

Comment: Never mind. [style.cssText] works on safari just fine, I'll just use that and use a string.

Answer (score 0):

For complex rules, use `ngClass` directive instead. Setup classes in your component styles

**component.css**

```
.gradient1 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
 }

.gradient2 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(black, white);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, white);
 }
```

Your component should determine which class is active; the class in turn applies the fallback values as defined in the CSS.

**component.ts**

```
// Will determine which class to apply.
getClass(){
  return someCondition ? 'gradient1' : 'gradient2';
}
```

Then in your template, just apply the class by binding to the function result.

**component.html**

```
<some-element [ngClass]="getClass()">...</some-element>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the colours come at runtime, which means I can't use this. I'll make that more clear in my answer