# Dynamically add classes inside *ngFor directive in angular5?

Tags: angular5

I have below few classes that has to applied to a div in `*ngFor` as shown below:

```
        <div class="row">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of tripTiles">
             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                   ...
                </div>
             </div>
           <ng-container>
        </div>
```

I have classes like `panel panel-primary`, `panel panel-green`, `panel panel-red` and `panel panel-yellow` how can i dynamically assign these classes.

Can i get any help or idea?..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ngClass] in div with conditions or variables, like in this answer:

[Dynamic classname inside ngClass in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2)

Example:

```
<div [ngClass]="[type === 'primary' ? 'panel-primary' : '']">
    ...
</div>
```