# Angular 7 attach only one class conditionally among fixed classes

Tags: angular, typescript

My question might be a basic stuff in Angular.

So I have this icon :

```
 <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg"
  (mouseenter)="animateLinkedin()"
  (mouseleave)="deanimateLinkedin()">
</i>
```

I need to add a class to it when hovering it, so I did this :

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }

    // Set to true on hover element
    linkedInHover = false;

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    animateLinkedin() {
        this.linkedInHover = true;
    }

    deanimateLinkedin() {
        this.linkedInHover = false;
    }
}
```

I need to activate the class if linkedInHover is set to true, **while keeping the current classes without any condition**.

How can I manage doing this since seemingly I can't do this with [ngClass] ?

**[EDIT]** I know when to use the normal CSS **:hover**, as I say, that's really not my need there because I use a third party css library, so I didn't write the class I want to attach.

Comment: I think you should just use the `:hover` selector from CSS for this.
See [here for more information](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: No that's not my need actually, I get the class from an external resource.

Comment: And why isn't [ngClass] not working? Like this: `[ngClass]="{'hover-class': linkedInHover }"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic classname inside ngClass in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with ngClass

```
<i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg" [ngClass]="{'<yourClass>':linkedInHover, '<anotherClass>':!linkedInHover}"
```

See [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) for further insight.

Comment: This works, but the `[class.bla]="condition"` is way cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with the `:hover` pseudo element, I will explain you how to do this without `ngClass`

You can do what you want the following way

```
<div class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg" [class.hover]="linkedInHover"></div>
```

But please use the `:hover` pseudo element for what you're doing as using angular for this is unneeded.

You can see other ways to do binding in the docs on 'template-syntax' [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets)

**Update**

Your question is a duplicate of the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2/37091329)

Please formulate your questions a bit more accurately next time, good luck!

Comment: I need javaScript for this because I get the class from an external css library, so I didn't write the class content, and in your code you didn't tell how can I still get my normal classes

Comment: @naspy971 you can still have your other classes separately? See updated answer

Comment: @naspy971 I see what you want now, see updated answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[class.className]` syntax like this:

```
<i 
  class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg" 
  (mouseenter)="animateLinkedin()" 
  (mouseleave)="deanimateLinkedin()"
  [class.classNameYouWantToApply]="linkedInHover">
</i>
```

You can also use `[ngClass]` like this:

```
<i 
  class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg" 
  (mouseenter)="animateLinkedin()" 
  (mouseleave)="deanimateLinkedin()"
  [ngClass]="linkedInHover ? 'classNameYouWantToApply': ''">
</i>
```

But I think you're over-complicating things here. You could simply use the CSS Preudo-Selector `:hover` to achieve the same thing.