# Angular 2 Doing an else with ngClass

Tags: html, angular, ng-class

I have the following template :

```
<p [ngClass]="{checked: condition, unchecked: !condition}">
```

While this is working, I find it a bit ugly as I have to repeat twice the condition. Is there a way to something like : `[ngClass]={condition ? checked : unchecked}` (which is not working)

Thanks

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Indeed

```
<p class="{{condition ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}}">
```

or

```
<p [ngClass]="condition ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'">
```

or

```
<p [ngClass]="[condition ? 'checked' : 'unchecked']">
```

---

### Angular 9 Update

But you should know that there's a difference in how different types of class bindings behave, especially when there are multiple types of class bindings on the same element.

And the new compiler, Ivy, brings more clarity and predictability to it. [Read More about it here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#styling-precedence)

Comment: It works, but I am very confused, is ngClass useless then ?

Comment: `[ngClass]="condition ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'"` should work as well.

Comment: @Scipion NO. you just have to find the right situation to use it, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283771/ng-class-in-angular2/36199294#36199294) for all possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir.