# How do you set mat-icon color and background color separately using two ternary expressions?

Tags: html, angular

I have a mat icon I'd like to be a certain color depending on the URL of the user (which is dealt with in the boolean expression). I used a ternary expression to change the background color which worked fine, but when I added the second ternary expression to change the color of the image/icon itself the first expression stopped working, and the second expression does not either.

```
<button class="button-spacer" [style.background-color]="atAnnouncements ? 'black' : 'white'" routerLink="/announcements" mat-mini-fab
            matTooltip="Announcements">
                <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': atAnnouncements ? '#D09B2C' : 'black'}">announcement</mat-icon>
            </button>
```

When leaving the ngStyle as a fixed color rather than ternary expression the first ternary works just fine.

So ideally, when atAnnouncements is true we have a black background color and the hex colored icon, and white background color and black icon when false.

Comment: does the same thing happen if you change the inner element to: `[style.color]="atAnnouncements ? '#D09B2C' : 'black'"`? Any console errors?

Comment: Why don't you just use a class on the button and set the colors through css?

Comment: It does not work or break it but throws this message: vendor.js:71107 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: that ngstyle approch is not binding the property color but the css class called .color. Iguess u didnt define it. Use the same approach like before --> ```[style.color]="atAnnouncements ? '#D09B2C' : 'black'"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
<button class="button-spacer" [style.background-color]="atAnnouncements ? 'black' : 'white'" routerLink="/announcements" mat-mini-fab
            matTooltip="Announcements">
                <mat-icon [ngClass]="{'true-color': atAnnouncements, 'false-color': !atAnnouncements  }">announcement</mat-icon>
            </button>
```

And in your css:

```
.true-color {
  color: green;
}

.false-color {
  color: red;
}
```

**or**

```
<button class="button-spacer" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': atAnnouncements ? 'black' : 'white' }" routerLink="/announcements" mat-mini-fab
            matTooltip="Announcements">
                <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': atAnnouncements ? '#D09B2C' : 'black'}">announcement</mat-icon>
            </button>
```

**or**

```
<button class="button-spacer" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': atAnnouncements ? 'black' : 'white' }" routerLink="/announcements" mat-mini-fab
                matTooltip="Announcements">
                    <mat-icon [ngClass]="atAnnouncements ? 'true-color' : 'false-color'"">announcement</mat-icon>
                </button>
```

[color test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgxqod)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ngClass] rather than [ngStyle]. This will keep the code cleaner in the template.

```
<button class="button-spacer" [style.background-color]="atAnnouncements ? 'black' : 'white'" routerLink="/announcements" mat-mini-fab
            matTooltip="Announcements">
                <mat-icon [ngClass]="{'color': atAnnouncements ? '#D09B2C' : 'black'}">announcement</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Here's a link to a similar problem: [Angular2 Doing an else with ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203030/angular2-doing-an-else-with-ngclass)

If you want to still use [ngStyle]: [Combine [NgStyle] With Condition (if..else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051496/combine-ngstyle-with-condition-if-else)

Comment: I dont think that he had a color class defined in css, thats why he is binding hex color codes to the condition.

Comment: I'm saying he should create a class to bind to in the template - it's cleaner plus reusable

Comment: It is, but u r not explaining that in the answer explicitly

Comment: Mate I have a question, r u sure that ur ngClass statement works? Cause this is giving me an error on stackblitz. Maybe leave out the curly brackets? or use these []?