# How to choose HTML according to the value while using ngFor in angular4?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

i am new to angular, suppose i have an array of values like this

```
domElement:Array<boolean>=[true,false,false,false,false,true,true,true];
```

and i want different html for true values and different html for false values while using ngFor, I followed this [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular-4#answer-43006589) and implemented this but it is not working

ie.

```
     <div *ngFor="let n of domElement; let i=index">   

<div *ngFor="let n of num; let i=index">

    <ng-template *ngIf="n; then gotValue else noValue"></ng-template>

    <ng-template #noValue>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            no value found - dummy element for no record !!!
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #gotValue>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            got values !!!
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want different code for only two specific case scenerio then you have to use. ***ngIf / else** not ***ngIf / then / else**. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular-4)

`<div *ngFor="let n of num">
    <template1 *ngIf="n%2 === 0; else other_content"></template1>
    <template2 #other_content></template2>
</div>`

2. If your code doesn't change and only thing that changes is styling than is better to use one common component with style replacement by **ng class directive**.

   - [Angular doc. explanation of NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)
   - [SO Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283771/ng-class-in-angular2)

`<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you defined two different block with the same name there is no #gotValue block in your code try this out:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of domElement">
    <ng-template *ngIf="n; then noValue else gotValue"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #noValue>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            no value found - dummy element for no record !!!
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #gotValue>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            got values !!!
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried to implement this but no matter what the value is i always get the <ng-template #noValue> displayed, please see my updated question, thank you

Comment: If my new implementation doesn't work for you, then please share with us the component code. It might be something that causes the n to be equal 'undefined' which means that the if clause will automatically redirect you to the false block.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<div *ngFor="let n of num">
    <template1 *ngIf="n%2 === 0"></template1>
    <template2 *ngIf="n%2 !== 0"></template2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let n of num; let i=index">
<div *ngIf="n%2===0;else gotValue"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        no value found - dummy element for no record !!!
    </div>
<ng-template #gotValue>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        got values !!!
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

You Don't need noValue ng-template. This worked for me. Hope it helps.